# JQuery div rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I've succeeded in rotating a div using this code:

```
function AnimateRotate(d){
    var elem = $("#arrow");

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
        duration: 200,
        step: function(now){
            elem.css({
                transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I'm now facing is trying to to the opposite back. Once the `div` been rotated and I click the div again then it just cycle through the code again and end up in the same place as before. But what I want is it to do the same thing but in the opposite direction.

To make some sense of what I'm talking about I've posted a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78DCU/1/).

Demonstrated in an image:

[image: Pro paint skills]

Comment: Any reason why you are not using CSS3 animations? It could be as simple as toggling a class

Comment: Agreed.  You're already using CSS3 for the rotation, so why not use transitions?

Comment: And if you still want to use javascript -> **http://jsfiddle.net/78DCU/4/**

Comment: @adeneo I had a similar idea :P http://jsfiddle.net/8Mv9h/

Comment: And with CSS3 -> **http://jsfiddle.net/78DCU/7/**

Comment: @adeneo Dang it! You beat me to it again! http://jsfiddle.net/8Mv9h/1/

Comment: For some reason I thought it was only possible to rotate images with CSS3 and not the `div` itself. Well, silly me. @adeneo, post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OP will surely deliver.

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this. Check whether the slide down conatiner is visible and call function with different parameters.

```
$( ".panel-heading" ).click(function() {
  var isVisible = $("#recipe-container").css("display");
if (isVisible == "block") {
    AnimateRotate(0, 90);
}  
else { 
AnimateRotate(90, 0);
}
$("#recipe-container").slideToggle();
});

function AnimateRotate(d,g){
var elem = $("#arrow");

$({deg: g}).animate({deg: d}, {
    duration: 200,
    step: function(now){
        elem.css({
            transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
        });
    }
});
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78DCU/1/

Answer (score 0):

I went for a more separate approach and utilized CSS to control the animations instead of jQuery.

By giving the main container a class of 'container--open', you can then set your styles on the child elements.

```
.container--open #recipe-container {
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
       -moz-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.container--open #arrow {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

This trims your jQuery code to:

```
var container = $('#container'),
    trigger   = $('.panel-heading');

trigger.on('click', function() {
    container.toggleClass('container--open');
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gs7pR/2/